# Pulling Receiver Enable Low for RS-485 Transceiver is being transmitted as a byte in Modbus packet

Tags: rs485, modbus

I am running into an issue where pulling RE low on my Max3441EESA is appearing as an extra byte in my Modbus message. I am currently testing the Modbus capability of my PIC32 MCU with a Modbus slave program on my PC, and even though I am transmitting an additional byte, the software still interprets and returns a message.  However, when communicating with a Modbus sensor, the communication fails, and I believe it might be due to the extra byte.

(Rx is what my MCU is sending and 00 is the extra byte)
[image: Output of Slave Program (Rx is what my MCU is sending)]

Below is a picture of my schematic.  It is important to note that I am not using the dedicated RTS for my chosen UART.  Unfortunately, I had to add a peripheral board to an existing design so I did not have the luxury of re-purposing the RTS pin; I had to choose a separate GPIO pin and try to use it as RE.
[image]

I can communicate between my MCU and the Windows Program, and between the Program and the Modbus sensor, so I know both my MCU and Modbus sensor *can* interface through Modbus.  For specifics, I am using Modbus RTU with a 38400 Baud Rate

Any ideas on how I can resolve this in hardware or software would be appreciated.  I have messed around with when I pull RE low, and I soldered up some solutions to try using different pins for RE to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The A and B are biased incorrectly, they should be biased the other way.

A-B must be positive for idle logic 1 state.

In your case, A-B is negative, logic 0.

Comment: Thank you, that was the exact fix.  I'm glad I can understand the theoretical aspects of the RS-485 circuits I've been working with a bit better.